# Why doesn't my divs take up 100% of the #area size?

Tags: html, css

Hello I want to insert my divs inside of `#area` but it doesnt work out.

```css
#area {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#area div { flex: 1; }

#exde { background-color: chocolate; }
#right { background-color: aqua; }
```

```html
<form action="http://www.google.lt" method="get">
  <div id="area">
    <div>
      <label for="exde">This is your text</label><br>
      <textarea name="tekstarea" rows="19" cols="10" id="exde"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="right">This is your text</label><br>
      <textarea name="tekstarea" rows="19" cols="10" id="right"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

So if someone could help me fill each of them to take half of the `#area` with chocolate color and the other half with blue I would be thankful.

Comment: Your divs take the right amount of place, the areas don't. Add width 100% to them to fix it

Comment: But the color still goes out of the border. For example if I added 100% width to #right it would make my blue color go out of the border.

Comment: Your user-agent is adding some border and padding to textareas, add padding: 0 and border : 0 to right and it will work properly

Answer (score 0):

They do:

```css
#area {width:400px;
  height:400px;
  display:flex;
  border: 1px solid red;}
  
  
#area div {
    flex:1;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
  
#exde {background-color:chocolate;}
#right {background-color:aqua;}
```

```html
<form action="http://www.google.lt" method="get">
  
  <div id="area">
   <div><label for="exde">This is your text</label><br>
    <textarea name="tekstarea" rows="19" cols="10" id="exde"></textarea></div>
  <div><label for="right">This is your text</label><br> 
    <textarea name="tekstarea" rows="19" cols="10" id="right"></textarea></div>
  </div>
  
  </form>
```

The `textarea`'s don't, so you might want to change their sizes.

For example, you might want to add this to your `css`:

```
#exde, #right {
     min-width: 100%;
     max-width: 100%;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#area {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#area div { flex: 1; }

#exde { background-color: chocolate; width:100%;box-sizing: border-box;}
#right { background-color: aqua; width:100%;box-sizing: border-box;}
```

```html
<form action="http://www.google.lt" method="get">
  <div id="area">
    <div>
      <label for="exde">This is your text</label><br>
      <textarea name="tekstarea" rows="19" cols="10" id="exde"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="right">This is your text</label><br>
      <textarea name="tekstarea" rows="19" cols="10" id="right"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is a simple solution of your problem, **add width 100% and box-sizing to both divs** like that:

```
#exde {background-color:chocolate;width:100%;box-sizing: border-box;}
#right {background-color:aqua;width 100%;box-sizing: border-box;}
```

**The box-sizing property defines how the width and height of an element are calculated.**